# IOS 16 UIPanGestureRecognizer cambiar el brillo con el gesto de paneo

Tags: ios, swift

Esta función funciona bien en iOS 15 pero no en iOS 16.
En iOS 16 aunque arrastres el dedo solo suma o resta una vez.
Muchas gracias por su respuesta

```swift
 @objc func pan(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        if recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.changed || recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.ended {
            let velocity:CGPoint = recognizer.velocity(in: self.view)
            if velocity.y > 0 {
                UIScreen.main.brightness -= 0.01
            } else {
                UIScreen.main.brightness += 0.01
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Qué extraño, con `0.01` y con `0.02` no funciona pero si con `0.03`.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta yo tampoco lo entiendo el número mínimo que soporta es `0.025001`